# How to set input value before sen ajax post requests?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How to set input value before sen ajax post requests ?

i wan to set

```
document.getElementById('input_id').value = "true";
```

before send ajax post

and set

```
document.getElementById('input_id').value = "false";
```

after send ajax success

but not work, How can i do ?

```
$('#loading').show();
document.getElementById('input_id').value = "true";
timer = setTimeout
(function ()
    {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'somepage.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
            {
                document.getElementById('input_id').value = "false";
                $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");                                                                             
                $('#demoajax').append(response);
            }
    });

    }, 2000
);
```

Comment: what is your html, does `input_id` exist?

Comment: yes, i have `<input type='hidden' id='input_id' name='input_id' value=''/>`

Comment: Have debugged it with developer tools? Are you sure you are getting a success response?

Comment: What does `console.log(document.getElementById('input_id').value)` show if you put this before the ajax request?

Comment: Maxxi,  Loading image show , but not have data in input id input_id

Answer (score 0):

Your code should do exactly what you want. See the JS console output. I think that the element does not exist or it is not an ID but a class name.

Furthermore, you should write all as jQuery, is easier ;-)

```
$('#loading').show();
$("#input_id").val("true");
timer = setTimeout(function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'somepage.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            $("#input_id").val("false");
            $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");                                                                             
            $('#demoajax').append(response);
        }
    });
}, 2000);
```